# Return as same value from database into bootstrap modal

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have my data displayed in table, and the way to edit and delete the data is in bootstrap modal. I'll just showing my delete modal. I used CodeIgniter 2.2.6:

My table:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<thead class="text-center">
    <th class="text-center">No.</th>
    <th class="text-center">Major Code</th>
    <th class="text-center">Major Name</th>
    <th class="text-center">Option</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php $no = 1; ?>
    <?php foreach ($select_major as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $no++;               ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->cd_major;      ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->name_major;    ?></td>
            <td align=center>
                <!-- DELETE BUTTON -->
                <a
                    class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"
                    role="button"
                    data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target="#modal-delete"
                    href="<?php
                        $cd_major   = $row->cd_major;
                        $name_major = $row->name_major;
                    ?>">
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash"></i> Delete
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

My Modal:

```
<!-- MODAL DELETE DATA -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url('major'); ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="id_major" value="<?php echo (isset($id_major) ? $id_major : ''); ?>" />
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>

                    <!-- MODAL TITLE -->
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash"></i> Delete Data</h4>
                </div>

                <!-- FORM -->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Are you sure to delete this major? <b><?php echo $name_major; ?></b> ini?</p>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="delete" value="Yes, delete" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div><!--/ .modal-content -->
    </div><!--/ .modal-dialog -->
</div><!--/ .modal -->
```

But when I try to delete the selected data, it always ordering to delete the last data. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: You should write javascript on delete link which will set ID in the modal field. and then model should open. because right now you last row id will get set into modal data and last record would get deleted.

Comment: I don't get it. Did you mean is on `<a>` link with `onClick` event?

Comment: Yes i mean to add onclick event on <a> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you would add code something like below:

Your new table:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<thead class="text-center">
    <th class="text-center">No.</th>
    <th class="text-center">Major Code</th>
    <th class="text-center">Major Name</th>
    <th class="text-center">Option</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php $no = 1; ?>
    <?php foreach ($select_major as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $no++;               ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->cd_major;      ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->name_major;    ?></td>
            <td align=center>
                <!-- DELETE BUTTON -->
                <a
                    class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"
                    role="button"
                    data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target="#modal-delete"
                    href="<?php
                        $cd_major   = $row->cd_major;
                        $name_major = $row->name_major;
                    ?>" onclick=deleteRecord(<?php $row->cd_major?>)>
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash"></i> Delete
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
<script>
function deleteRecord(id){
    document.getElementById("id_major").value = id;
}
</script>
```

Your new modal:

```
<!-- MODAL DELETE DATA -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url('major'); ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="id_major" id="id_major" value="<?php echo (isset($id_major) ? $id_major : ''); ?>" />
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>

                    <!-- MODAL TITLE -->
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash"></i> Delete Data</h4>
                </div>

                <!-- FORM -->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Are you sure to delete this major? <b><?php echo $name_major; ?></b> ini?</p>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="delete" value="Yes, delete" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div><!--/ .modal-content -->
    </div><!--/ .modal-dialog -->
</div><!--/ .modal -->
```

Please use the code which i have given you, it should work now.

I assume cd_major is the id of the row which you want to delete, if not, you can replace the field name in the function which we have added to `<a>` tag in onclick event.

Thanks